# UILabel.text in another ViewController returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, uilabel

I'm trying to change the text in a label in one ViewController by clicking a button in another ViewController.

```
class Home: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
var add = AddNew()

@IBAction func buttonChangeText(_ sender: Any) {
    add.printText(text: "TEXT")
}
```

this is the code for the first view controller

```
class AddNew: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var labelTextText: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

func printText(text:String) {
     labelTextText?.text = text
 }
```

This is the code for the second vc.
If I try to change it it does not do anything. I also tried printing it and it just printed nil. If I print or change it from the same view controller it does work.

Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using  a segue to switch between the controllers, so first add a text property to AddNew ViewController, then change your prepareForSegue to

```
if segue.identifier == "yourSegueName" {
    let addNewVC = segue.destinationViewController as! AddNew
    AddNew?.text = "TEXT"
}
```

then, when you load your AddNew VC,
change labelTextText to the text variable you defined earlier

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to fix.

**labelTextText** is created and referenced from UI interface like as .storyboard or .xib because it has IBOutlet.
So, you have to get new instance of Class **AddNew** via following static function.

```
class AddNew: UIViewController {
    class func storyboardInstance() -> AddNew {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddNew") as! AddNew
    }
}
```

This is new method.

```
var add = AddNew.storyboardInstance()

@IBAction func buttonChangeText(_ sender: Any) {
    add.printText(text: "TEXT")
}
```